# Can we define more than a single Plugin class in a Gradle buildSrc

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a pretty typical Gradle library project that contains a collection of modules (either Android or pure Java) that depend on some common configuration.

This common configuration is abstracted into a "publishConfig.gradle" file (which is read in via `apply` in those build.gradle files that need it) and some custom Tasks captured in a buildSrc. This question is about the latter.

The buildSrc is a single module/project consisting of source (as Groovy) in a specific package as a single Groovy file with two classes: the class that implements `Plugin` and the plugin extension class. *e.g.*:

`org.clvrmnky.gradle.plugins.LibraryPlugin`

This configuration and the defined Tasks work without error. No problem there.

Now I want to add additional custom tasks for a different reason (remember, this is all part of a shared custom configuration for a growing number of submodules to the root project) so I added a parallel class file that defines a new plugin class implementing `Plugin`. *e.g.*:

`org.clvrmnky.gradle.plugins.BuildBreaker`

For reference, here is the class and task definition snippet:

```
[...]
public class BuildBreaker implements Plugin<Project> {
    static def authString = fetchSonarAuthString()

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("buildbreaker", BuildBreakerExtension)

        project.task([
            description: 'Fail this task if the Sonarqube Quality Gate does not pass.',
            dependsOn: ["sonarqube"]
        ], 'breakOnBadQualityGate') {
[...]
```

That is, the class and task methods are defined similarly, but have different String identifiers.

However, when I do this, the new Tasks I define are not visible to the root project or any submodule of the project:

```
PS C:\rd\SOPLibs\Commons> .\gradlew.bat  breakOnBadQualityGate
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
[...]    
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'breakOnBadQualityGate' not found in root project 'Commons'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option
 to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The `build` directory contains classes for all the source, and there is a lib jar that contains these classes which I *presume* is being supplied to the Gradle classpath at runtime. That is, this is building and packaging without error.

I've seen hints that you need to tweak the buildSrc build.gradle on multi-project buildSrc projects so that all the jars are on the classpath at runtime, but in this case we have a single jarfile with multiple Plugin tasks.

I've also tried moving the BuildBreaker class to a separate package, but this did not solve the problem.

Can we not implement more than one `Plugin` class in a single buildSrc, even if they have different classnames? Or do I have to split these out into multiple buildSrc projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define as many plugins and tasks as you like in `buildSrc`. But nothing will take effect until you

```
 apply plugin: foo.bar.MyPlugin
```

Or

```
task foo(type: com.foo.MyTask) {...}
```

Comment: Dammit. Of course. There it is, the first plugin in each module build.gradle where I put it. I _knew_ it had something to do with class visibility and... d'oh.